# How to disable commas on Integer field in Edit item screen

Tags: field-definition

I have a field defined as this:

```
<Field Type="Integer" DisplayName="BŠS" Required="FALSE" Commas="FALSE" Group="CRPU grupa" ID="{f8ae007e-df89-4149-8318-a79673cec338}" SourceID="{e0015c45-f539-484b-ae04-b792801053e3}" StaticName="BŠS" Name="BŠS"  />
```

This is a part of a custom content type, which is added to a list. When I display an item, the field displays ok, without commas (or points depending on the language pack I guess)

> BŠS 434343

but if I try to edit, it shows them like this:

> BŠS  434.343

Is there any way of changing this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I have only seen this problem when fields were created as Number field, like

```
<Field Type="Number" DisplayName="DemoNumber" Required="FALSE" Group=" Demo Field" ID="{1221b2d2-992d-4abf-a80a-55585c234c55}" SourceID="{e834bd2e-72bf-4aab-9ef4-4f3e118526e2}" StaticName="DemoNumber" Name="DemoNumber" Decimals="0" Percentage="FALSE"/>
```

Did you by any chance create this field first as a number and then change its type to Integer later?

Comment: Hmm, I have indeed. Any idea on how to fix it?